# implementing authentication and authorization using JWT token

Tags: authentication, oauth, asp.net-core, authorization, jwt

I am just confuse to use UseJwtBearerAuthentication or JWT with OAUTH 2 for implementing authentication and authorization in .Net Core Web API.

Answer (score 2):

JSON Web Token (JWT) is an implementation of OAUTH 2.

[ASP.NET Core and Angular 2 by Valerio De Sanctis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/178646568X) explains very detail on how to implement JWT provider in ASP.NET Core. Here is the sample code -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app...)
{
     ...
    // Add a custom Jwt Provider to generate Tokens
    app.UseJwtProvider();

    // Add the Jwt Bearer Header Authentication to validate Tokens
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
    {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = JwtProvider.SecurityKey,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = JwtProvider.Issuer,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the sample code is written in previous version of ASP.NET Core which used `project.json`. I convert the project to `csproj` at [GitHub](https://github.com/winlwinoonet).